# Using /mnt vs /media for Transmission storage on external hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, mount, data-transfer

I was wondering if it makes a difference to mount an external hard drive at `/mnt` vs `/media`. 
I'm making a Transmission seedbox using an *RPi 3b+*, and different tutorials are suggesting different things.

I know the RPi automatically mounts external hard drives at `/media`. Would it make sense to just point transmission to a download folder in `/media` instead of the extra work required to have my RPI automount an ext drive at `/mnt` and point transmission there. Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The default names and structure for linux are defined in the [Linux Standard Base (LSB)](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml).

Part of this document is the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

Herein you find the definition for [/media : Mount point for removable media](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s11.html)
and for [/mnt : Mount point for a temporarily mounted filesystem](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s12.html).

So if your harddrive is removable (e.g. USB-drive) it will be mounted automatically under **/media** when you plug it in. So nothing is to do. If it is static and you have to mount it manually or within `/etc/fstab` you should mount it under **/mnt**.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference where you mount the drive. HOWEVER the automatic mounting process creates directories under `/media` which can be problematic.

I recommend that manual mounted storage use `/mnt`